SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'demostore.ps_bids' doesn't exist
i created an updatebids.php where given the case, if certain amount of users share the same bet, this has to update to 1 extra euro/dollar. In the picture even same user can bet the same amount :/


Here´s the query
 UPDATE {$dbPrefix}auction_bid_details AS b1
                JOIN (
                    SELECT id_bid, bid_price, id_customer, 
                           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id_customer, id_bid, bid_price ORDER BY id_bid) AS rank
                    FROM {$dbPrefix}auction_bid_details
                ) AS ranked_bids
                ON b1.id_bid = ranked_bids.id_bid
                SET b1.bid_price = b1.bid_price + 1
                WHERE ranked_bids.rank > 1


This are the logs while using the function, no errors atm :
    /*
  0: "update_bids.php script started."
​​
1: "Attempting database connection.. Array .  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"
​​
2: "Database connection established.   . >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
​​
3: "Starting bid update process..."
​​
4: "Bids updated successfully!"
​​
5: "update_bids.php script ended."
​​
length: 6
    */
        

Frontend in smarty, where inputs will be handled. Ajax is being used
    
    
                // Perform the AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/update_bids.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        bid_amount: bidAmount,
                        auction_id: auctionId,
                        customer_id: customerId
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Log the response for debugging
                         console.log("Auction ID:", auctionId, "Customer ID:", customerId, "Bid Amount:", bidAmount);
    
                        // Optionally, update the page or show a success message
                        // $('.wk-success').html('<p>Bid submitted successfully!</p>');
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        // Log the error for debugging, i think this one is being fired :(
                        console.error(xhr.responseText);
    
                     }
   



is it update_bids.php or updatebids.php? Your ajax points to the former but the latter is referenced in the question. Also ps_bids does not appear in the sql shown so how has that been derived?

As @ProfessorAbronsius mentioned, it looks like you are looking in the wrong query. I'm sure update_bids.php is correct since this is also what the error log is reporting but you are trying to solve your issue by looking at the wrong query. Nowhere in that SQL query, was there a ps_bids so inside the same file there is something else going wrong.

Echo the $sql, copy it and execute it against your database.
My bet is that {$dbPrefix}bids evaluates to ps_bids which appearantly doesn't exit.

Updated the query, my bad i did not identify the ps_bids and other fields. I added a db picture, there were no errors while running the query. But backend's behaviour of prestashop still persists. i.e., several users can bet the same amount.

This seems to do the trick, to handle parallel requests and updating the bid:
 $sql = "UPDATE {$dbPrefix}auction_bid_details AS b1
                JOIN (
                    SELECT id_bid, bid_price, id_customer, automatic_bid_price, 
                           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id_customer, id_bid, bid_price ,automatic_bid_price ORDER BY id_bid) AS rank
                    FROM {$dbPrefix}auction_bid_details
                ) AS ranked_bids
                ON b1.id_bid = ranked_bids.id_bid
                SET b1.automatic_bid_price = b1.automatic_bid_price + 1  
                WHERE ranked_bids.rank > 1
          "  ;




 try {
            // Begin the transaction
            $db->beginTransaction();

            // Lock the table
            $lockSql = "LOCK TABLES {$dbPrefix}auction_bid_details WRITE";
            $db->exec($lockSql);

            // Execute the update query
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                customLog("Bids updated successfully!");
            } else {
                customLog("Error updating bids: " . implode(", ", $stmt->errorInfo()));
                customLog($sql);
            }

            // Unlock the table
            $unlockSql = "UNLOCK TABLES";
            $db->exec($unlockSql);

            // Commit the transaction
            $db->commit();

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // Rollback the transaction in case of error
            $db->rollBack();
            customLog("SQL Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }

